# Create a method at runtime in java without using reflection

Tags: java, performance

I have a map of objects like below,

```
<key1, ClassAobj>
<key2, ClassBobj>
<key3, ClassCobj>
<key4, ClassDobj>
```

Number of objects in map are unknown. I am invoking a method on those objects iteratively.

```
for key in keyset {
    stringbuilder.append(map.get(key).getData())
}
```

but at large scale, this iteration and stringbuilder.append causes a performance issue i.e. it takes time. I was thinking of creating a runtime method which creates a stribuilder like,

```
getdata() {

   return (stringbuilder(map.get(key1).getdata() + map.get(key2).getdata() + map.get(key3).getdata() + ... + till all entries in map ))    

}
```

Is it the right approach? Please suggest if any better approach if available with examples.

I have tried java reflection and it is much slower that current iterator version and thus avoided it.

P.S. Ignore syntax considering this as pseudocode.

Comment: You think that creating an entire method at runtime will ever be faster than a sringbuilder?

Comment: I think the performance on string builder is the underlying growing char array. You should supply an expected length in the string builder constructor.

Comment: @MouseEvent I think your comment, with a little more explanation, is worth an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuilder` is by far the most efficient way to do string concatination, given that you know what's going on.

Internally, the builder has a fixed char array storing the appended values at every append. What happens when the array fills up? Similar to `ArrayList`, a new array with `arr.length * 2` is allocated and values are copied over to the new array. This process is repeated over and over as long needed.

The default length, according to the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is 16. In the event that you know the approximate length of the resulting string, the better way off would be to supply that length in the constructor. This will reduce extra overhead afterwards.